# Creating softmax from a tf.distributions.Categorical output layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, softmax

I'm training an agent to act in a discrete environment, and I'm using a `tf.distributions.Categorical` output layer which I then sample to create a softmax output to determine what action to take. I create my policy network like this:

```
pi_eval, _ = self._build_anet(self.state, 'pi', reuse=True)

def _build_anet(self, state_in, name, reuse=False):
    w_reg = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(L2_REG)
    with tf.variable_scope(name, reuse=reuse):
        layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(state_in, HIDDEN_LAYER_NEURONS, tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=w_reg, name="pi_l1")
        layer_2 = tf.layers.dense(layer_1, HIDDEN_LAYER_NEURONS, tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=w_reg, name="pi_l2")
        a_logits = tf.layers.dense(layer_2, self.a_dim, kernel_regularizer=w_reg, name="pi_logits")
        dist = tf.distributions.Categorical(logits=a_logits)
    params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope=name)
    return dist, params
```

I then sample the network and build up a class distribution output to act as a softmax output, using the example from the [tf.distributions.Categorical webpage](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Categorical):

```
n = 1e4
self.logits_action = tf.cast(tf.histogram_fixed_width(values=pi_eval.sample(int(n)), value_range=[0, 1], nbins=self.a_dim), dtype=tf.float32) / n
```

Run like this:

```
softmax = self.sess.run([self.logits_action], {self.state: state[np.newaxis, :]})
```

But the outputs only ever have two non-zero entries:

```
[0.44329998 0.         0.         0.5567    ]
[0.92139995 0.         0.         0.0786    ]
[0.95699996 0.         0.         0.043     ]
[0.7051 0.     0.     0.2949]
```

My hunch is something to do with `value_range` which the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/histogram_fixed_width) says:

> value_range: Shape [2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/histogram_fixed_width) Tensor of same dtype as values. values <=
>   value_range[0] will be mapped to hist[0], values >= value_range[1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Categorical)
>   will be mapped to hist[-1].

But I'm not sure what value range I should use?  I wonder if anyone had any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as I suspected it was something to do with the `value_range` and I should set the upper size to the action dimension:

```
value_range=[0, self.a_dim]
```